# I add woocommerce product category using SQL query. But I think the slug is not perfect there because its getting 404

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I got all category list in admin but when I am updating category it's working so the problem with the slug.

How I can regenerate all slugs?

[image]

Comment: update the permalink settings?

Comment: NO that's not working I have try that

Comment: do you have any special character in slug?

Comment: yes I am using local language  like http://localhost/eshop/product-category/%e0%a6%b8%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%ac%e0%a6%be%e0%a6%b8%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%a5%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%af-%e0%a6%8f%e0%a6%ac%e0%a6%82-%e0%a6%ab%e0%a6%bf%e0%a6%9f%e0%a6%a8%e0%a7%87%e0%a6%b8/

Comment: check the 60 record slug. It is something encode format

Comment: what is that and where will I find it, sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203453/discussion-between-shakil-hossain-and-vel).